# Нарисовать пиксель, если стоит нестандартное масштабирование

Tags: c++, графика, direct2d

Как нарисовать пиксель с помощью `ID2D1RenderTarget::FillRectangle` если в настройках Windows установлено нестандартное масштабирование? Например, 99 DPI. Если масштаб 100%, то можно так (пиксель будет в точке 9, 9):

```
_target->FillRectangle(
    D2D1::RectF(
        8.f, 8.f, 9.f, 9.f
    ),
    _currentBrush
);
```

Тот же код при большем DPI выдаёт что-то такое:

[image: не пиксель]

(здесь разлиновано по пикселям)

Как всё-таки правильно нарисовать пиксель?

Comment: А что такое "правильно" в вашем понимании?

Comment: @Kromster Так, чтобы был нарисован один пиксель, а не 4, как на рисунке. (То есть, на аналогичном изображении закрашен один квадратик)

Comment: Так, еще уточнение, а если масштаб не 99%, а например 10% или 1000% - сколько должно быть пикселов нарисовано, 1 и 1, или 0,01 и 100 ?

Comment: @Kromster 1 и 1. И 99% и 99 DPI это разные вещи вообще-то.

Comment: То есть вы хотите, независимо от масштаба/dpi выводить 1 пиксель задавая координаты 8f - 9f.

Comment: @Kromster нет, не обязательно такие координаты, но чтобы с помощью метода FillRectangle и при произвольном DPI.

Comment: Продолжаю намекать, при DPI 10, с координатами прямоугольника 8 - 9, должно закраситься сколько пикселей, 1 или 10?

Comment: @Kromster если вы знаете, как решить проблему, то почему бы не ответить на вопрос? Зачем «намекать»?

Comment: я не знаю *как* решить проблему, т.к. не обладаю необходимыми условиями и ограничениями. Мой вам ответ - представьте какой результат должен быть при 10dpi и при 1000dpi, и почему 99dpi должны или не должны подчиняться интерполяции между этими крайностями. За сим, откланиваюсь.

Comment: Так вы рисуйте в физических пикселях. Разрешение экрана-то остается неизменным.

Comment: @VTT я как раз и спрашиваю, как это сделать. Например, если умножить все координаты на 99/96 , все равно будет нарисовано несколько пикселей.

Comment: Так ничего умножать не надо, в физических пикселах координаты не меняются. Может у вас приложение не объявлено как [DPI-aware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt843498(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @VTT Я разобрался, у меня рисование происходило не напрямую в HwndRenderTarget, а в BitmapRenderTarget с неправильным DPI, который потом уже выводился в окно. Можно, как вы наверно имели в виду, установить `SetDPI(96.f, 96.f)` и рисовать в пикселях, иначе можно умножить все координаты на 96/99 (если DPI 99) и будет то же самое.

Comment: Сначала определите размер области вывода в пространстве устройства. Пусть это будет NxM пикселей.